# Meteor Mongo not working but standalone MongoDB is

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5464e68481f8252e74f6e0ef"),
    "message" : "Hello World!",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-11-13T17:12:36.547Z"),
    "sender" : "D3EkLv8vatX3xfCGE",
    "receiver" : [
        {
            "id" : "YzhZchz4AwCAd3q2R",
            "seen" : false
        },
        {
            "id" : "sm2W28EKYmHz29Aoj",
            "seen" : false
        }
    ],
    "saved" : false
}
```

That's the basic structure. Now I want to get all the documents that have the current user's ID. The id can be in the sender field or one of the object in the receiver array. This works fine:

`db.messages.find({ sender: "D3EkLv8vatX3xfCGE" })`

But the following query doesn't work on the Meteor Mongo instance but does so in Mongo 2.6:

`db.messages.find({ receiver: {id: "YzhZchz4AwCAd3q2R"} })`

Is there any way I can get this to work. Also, the above query works on Minimongo but doesn't work on Meteor's bundled mongo(`meteor mongo`) which is currently at v2.4.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all of the documents were a particular user is a receiver using `receiver.id` in your selector like so:

```
Messages.find({'receiver.id': 'YzhZchz4AwCAd3q2R'})
```

If you wanted to find all documents where a particular user was either a receiver **or** a sender you could do this:

```
var id = 'YzhZchz4AwCAd3q2R';
Messages.find({$or: [{'receiver.id': id}, {sender: id}]});
```

Answer (score 1):

On mongo shell this query seems to work:

```
db.messages.find({ "receiver.id": "YzhZchz4AwCAd3q2R"} )
```